# How to open iOS app home page with iTunes on Mac OSX programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id{app ID}7?mt=8"]]
```

This doesn't work and it says "There is no application set to open the URL itms-apps:.......".

**Edit**

I found the solution, use `@"itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id{app ID}7?mt=8"` rather than `itms-apps`

Comment: iOS app can't run on Mac OSX.

Comment: @GeneCode, i only want to open the app home page in iTunes